I need help having functions run on different tabs that change through a form submit
I have run into an issue.
I have a project where multiple people submit answers through Google Forms, which then populates a spreadsheet, that then separates the data into 12 separate tabs dependent on an option chosen in the form. This part I have already figured out.
The issue I am having is that I don't know how to get a function to run that checks if a specific cell was changed on a tab through a formula that references data pulled from the form submission, and then executes another function.
For example, I have this formula in one cell on each tab:
=if(and(E12>(E13+10),B12="Check Out",B13="Check In"), "1", "")
and if those conditions are met, the cell changes to display "1".
When that happens on any tab, I want a function to automatically trigger.
I am aware that the onEdit trigger only works with manual input and change.
Is there a way to do this?
I have looked into the installable trigger onChange, but from what I can tell, that trigger can't be used to check only 1 cell value.

Use onFormSubmit trigger and check the new values in the trigger event object e against the sheet values. Easier said than done though.

Along with TheMaster's comment please add information about what you have tried and what you currently have so the community can provide better suggestion or answer to your question.

I don't know how to get a function to run that checks if a specific cell was changed on a tab through a formula that references data pulled from the form submission It would be helpful to have an MRE to understand exactly how your scenario works. BUT, if the formula is a direct consequence of the form submission, then @TheMaster is right, extend your onFormSubmit function to address this possibility. OTOH, if the formula is a result of user input, use onEdit to detect the change in value and execute your formula.

There are no  triggers that fire on changes on a spreadsheet due to formula changes or other scripts.
